# User Directory Identification

Tags: powershell

I need to create a script to iterate through a list of user samaccountnames and identify network directories matching their samaccountname on the network.  It doesn't seem to work though. Users home folders on the network use their samaccountname in the path.  Here is what I have so far:

```
$userList = "C:\Users\sfp01\My 
Documents\Data_Deletion_Testing\User_SamAccountName.csv"

$userDirectory = foreach ($user in $userList) 
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path "\\ceoii\" -Directory -Recurse | ? {}
}
Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\sfp01\My 
Documents\Data_Deletion_Testing\User_Directory.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to import the csv as your first line just saves the location of the file in the variable rather than the contents of the file.

Second, you didn't provide the column name of the csv file that contains the user's saMAccountName. You'll need to set up your `Where-Object` to filter using that information. I am using `-match` on saMAccountName, but edit this to reflect your requirements.

And I don't think that `\\servername\` isn't a valid share name, it should be a share like `\\servername\share\` If you want to get all the  shares from a server you could enumerate them with something like this `invoke-command -ComputerName ceoii -ScriptBlock {Get-SmbShare}`

You also probably want to only pull the list of folders once and then filter for each user.

Lastly, you save the information in `$userDirectory` so you'll want to pipe that information into your `export-csv`.

```
$userList = Import-CSV 'C:\Users\sfp01\My Documents\Data_Deletion_Testing\User_SamAccountName.csv'

$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\ceoii\sharename" -Directory -Recurse

$userDirectory = foreach ($user in $userList) {
    $folders | Where-Object {$_.name -match $user.saMAcountName}
}

$userDirectory | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\sfp01\My Documents\Data_Deletion_Testing\User_Directory.csv'
```

More efficient than that would be to use `-in` or `-contains` if you know that the folder names exactly match.

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\ceoii\sharename" -Directory -Recurse
$userList = Import-CSV 'C:\Users\sfp01\My Documents\Data_Deletion_Testing\User_SamAccountName.csv' |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty saMAccountName
$folders |
    Where-Object {$_.name -in $userList} |
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\sfp01\My Documents\Data_Deletion_Testing\User_Directory.csv'
```

Comment: Ok, I am not understanding the column name on the csv file part.  I don't have any column headings.  There is only one column of data on the csv file, all saMAccountNames.

Comment: Then use Get-Content.

Comment: Then you don't have a CSV file but rather a plain-text file that contains a list of sAMAccountNames. CSV means "comma-separated values." CSV is text-readable, but it is a specific format.

Comment: Well, to be fair, a single column does fit the format described in the RFC. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#page-2

Comment: You can even use Import-CSV with a single column file. In this case you would have to specify the -Header. Of course doing that is kind of silly since Get-Content would be easier.

Comment: Yes, a single-column file can be _treated_ as a CSV, but if it has no header line and no commas, it seems silly to call it a CSV in the first place; it's just a list.